# Sonar Upgrade - Technical debt is different

Tags: sonarqube

I am upgrading from sonar 3.3.2 to sonarqube 4.5.1. I am comparing one project in each version. Everything looks good except the technical debt and the unit tests.

Why is this happening?

Here is the technical debt in 3.3.2:

[image]

Here is the technical debt in 4.5.1:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past when I get 0 TD & 0 Issues, it has been because sonar runner did not analyze the appropriate files either because the sonar.language was wrong or the exclusion patterns resulted in a few/no files to analyze. Try drilling down to see which files got analyzed by clicking on issues "0"

I would also check the activated rules to see if the rules that found issues got deactivated. To do this, check the logs for the quality profile sonar runner used then go to Quality Profiles on your sonar site & check that profile to make sure it has activated rules

Comment: what was the underlying problem @ChrisBolton ? Did the rules get deactivated or files were not analyzed ?

Comment: The rules got deactivated.